# WordPress Parmalink/URL Slug not shown properly

Tags: wordpress, urlencode

I want to display permalink as shown in following image

[image]

This is the same URL I got from WordPress, when I created the post as shown in following picture.

[image]

But whenever I copy the URL from this, I  get URL as follow
[https://gappatappa.xyz/%e0%a4%95%e0%a5%8b%e0%a4%b0%e0%a5%8b%e0%a4%a8%e0%a4%be-%e0%a4%86%e0%a4%a3%e0%a5%80-%e0%a4%ad%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%9c%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%be%e0%a4%b2%e0%a4%be/](https://gappatappa.xyz/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE/)

When user clicks on this URL he gets redirected to the correct page, but I have to share this encrypted string with my users. I want to share the link as "[http://gappatappa.xyz/कोरोना-आणी-भाजीपाला](http://gappatappa.xyz/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%80-%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE)"
How can  I do that?

Comment: Share the link exactly as you have it - the browser handles it automatically. The browser will take the encoded URL and "prettify" it to your language. I clicked on your link: http://gappatappa.xyz/कोरोना-आणी-भाजीपाला and the URL was in Marathi.

Comment: Actually the browser is not handling it. It shows  the URL in encrypted format

Comment: I can see the correct language in my browser URL. Also, it's not encrypted, it's encoded. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Same: https://imgur.com/a/csMNcBP

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from WordPress dashboard menu Settings >> Permalinks

Save it twice just and I hope it solve your issue.

Comment: That's not what OP is asking. OP wants that URL to not be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when you change the URL permalinks format from WordPress' settings. You can resolve this issue by following the below steps. I recently fixed this issue for a client.

1. Clear cache using plugins like w3 total cache WP plugin
2. Now clear App Cache
3. Go to setting-->Permalinks and save setting twice

After following the above steps, your issue should be resolved. I hope this will work for you as well.